# How To Add A New Page Template To Wordpress Template Dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I hope someone might be able to help me with this.
I have had a new page template built for a wordpress website and have uploaded it to the theme folder. However can someone tell me how to add that page template to the drop down menu in the page editor so it can be selected.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add this snippet to the very top of the file.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Put Your Template Name Here
*/
?>
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template